# Body background and footer on bottom of page

Tags: html, css, background, footer

I can't find a solution to this issue. I would like to have a footer that's always at the bottom (not sticky/fixed), and also a background that's always at the bottom (not sticky/fixed).

I made a picture to make it more clear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe9ZO.png

```
<html>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="content">
   <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <h2>Footer</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; background: url('http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/New-York-Skyline-Downdown-view.jpg') no-repeat bottom center; }

#container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; }

.content { max-width: 800px; width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; background: #eee; margin-top: 20px; text-align: center; padding-top: 30px; }

.footer { max-width: 800px; width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #000; margin: auto auto 0 auto; }
```

I also made a codepen: https://codepen.io/nickm10/pen/XVJjGb

Anyone know the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `.footer { position:absolute; top: 100%; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; max-width: 800px; width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #000; }` , also place the footer tag outside the `container div` , had to add `top: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using flexbox layout. There is something called as `flex-grow` (The flex-grow property specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container).

Just give:

```
.content{
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;    
    flex-grow: 1;
   /** remove height **/
}
```

and remove height from `.content`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the decire height of the html page. Else the page is high enough to fit all of ur element;
     `html, body { height: 1000px; }`

Comment: I don't think giving a fixed height should be a solution. Every sub page will have a different height.

Comment: then add a space div

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100%;` for html and body instead of `height: 100%;`

**Updated answer:**

html height should be set as min-height so it can grow when needed. But thanks to this body does not know the theight of parent (html) element and so we can't use % based min-height there anymore.
Thankfully we have viewport units. So for body set `min-height: 100vh;` This tells body to be minimally 100% of viewports height.

```
html { min-height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; }
```

PS! You also need to remove margin from body with this solution. Or there will be a scrollbar visible always.

Answer (score 0):

Put background in body pseudo element and align it there.

```css
body {
  ...
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  ...
}
body::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/New-York-Skyline-Downdown-view.jpg")
    no-repeat bottom center;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a codepen: [codepen.io/anon/pen/vpEgxo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpEgxo)

Hope this will help ;)